# Cocoa release a static variable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've created a class that uses a static NSSet to define some elements shared by every instance of my class.

To define this se i use this code:

```
myStaticSet = [[NSSet setWithObjects:
                         @"element one",
                         @"element two",
                         nil
                         ]retain];
```

As you can see i retain the set.

I really can't understand where i can release `myStaticVariable` i'm pretty sure that i can't release it in `dealloc`... so is there a way to release a static variable ?

//EDIT
It could be a good solution adding a new class method to release static value ?

```
+(void)cleanstatic{
    [mystatic release];
}
```

and call it when i'm sure i'm done with this class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a static variable and want to release it, perhaps it shouldn't be static after all? Is it used throughout the entire lifetime of the application? In that case I'd say you don't have to bother releasing it.

Otherwise, if you have some common 'endpoint' for the code using this variable, that would be the place to get rid of it.

Comment: Sure, that's possible, but it's quite error prone in for example a multi-threaded scenario. If it's possible I'd rather recommend refactoring your code in order to get it into an instance variable, which you can then handle in accordance and release when done with. Is there something something in particular that makes you want to release the variable? Does it hold a lot of data?

Comment: It takes only 20 strings, but i'm looking for the right way to write this code. I think that creating 20 strings for every instance of this class it's not the correct way, thus, i've thought to adopt static variable. So, in a multithread scenario this implementation would be a big mess ?

Comment: Well, it depends if you're going to change the variable. If it's constant, you could as well make it just that; a constant. Then multiple threads wouldn't pose a problem. If it's caching you're after, you have for example NSCache to handle stuff like releasing its content (but then you'd have to load the data from e.g. a file).

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't release it. As you said, it's shared by every instance of your class, and you can never be sure that you won't be creating new instances. Thus, the set should exist as long as your app is running.